# Master page data is missing in sapui5 split app?

Tags: routes, sapui5

I have two screens in my app and I am using routing as followed.

From screen1 to MasterView page in screen2

master page routing is like `MasterView/{collegeName}`.

In screen2, after selection from the list Routing to DetailView in the same screen

Detail page routing is like `DetailView/{regdNum}/{studentName}`

Now if **I reload my screen2** this routing pattern is matched but the pattern for `MasterView/{collegeName}`is not matching.

I am using attachPatternMatched for getting data from the server and bind to view.
So that I am missing my Master page data.

How to handle this issue?